# How to write parameterized xpath?

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have a dropdown menu, "Select Work Area", below is the xpath(using firebug) and html code for that.
The problem is that the xpath keeps on changing. How to parameterize the xpath for this? 
Like, with one xpath, i need to write a function which can be used for calling the other.

xpath -> `.//*[@id='step-content-2']/div/md-content/form/div/div[1]/div[1]/md-card[1]/md-card-content/form-field-panel/div/ul/li[2]/div/div/div/span/span/span[1]`

html -> `<span class="k-input" unselectable="on">Select Work Area...</span>`

The dropdown contains 4 names, below are its xpath and html

xpath --> `html/body/div[3]/div/div[3]/ul/li[1]`

html  --> `<li class="k-item" data-offset-index="0" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">Cheyenne</li>`

xpath --> `html/body/div[3]/div/div[3]/ul/li[2]`

html  --> `<li class="k-item" data-offset-index="1" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">Pueblo</li>`

and 2 more.

My code:

```
def _selectWorkArea(self, text): 
   self.ui.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[contains(text()=\'{}\')'.format(text)).click()

def selectName(self, name):
    self._selectWorkArea(name)
```

Comment: Can you please share the HTML source or the URL of your website.

Comment: As @Monika mentioned update the question with the relevant HTML as well as your code trials and error(if any)

Comment: @Monika updated my trail code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use something that isn't being randomly generated such as the span text?

So you could do something like:

```
self.ui.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Select Work Area...']")
```